# How to convert single row value into another table row in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need to insert Table1 Col1 value into Table2 Col1:

Input:

```
Table1
Col1
1,2,3,4
```

Output:

```
Table2
Col1
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_split_to_table()`:

```
select val
from table1 t1 cross join lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(t1.col1, ',') val;
```